# COUNT records returned by group by

Tags: sql-server

How to select count the records returned by group by?

I have 13 records in 1 table that when I group by 1 field, would return 1 record.

But when I use `select count(*)` it still returns 13 instead of 1.

How can I achieve the result I want?

Comment: Show us your query, some sample data and your expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count(*)` is counting each item under the field use `count(distinct field)` this will give you the result